# How to deal with this differential equation with boundary values?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

In my research I have come across the following problem that I am trying to solve numerically.

I have

$$
\frac{d}{dr} \left[ \frac{1}{r^2 \rho(r)} \left( \frac{d \psi(r)}{dr} \right) \right]
+
\frac{4\pi G \rho(r)}{r^2 P(r)} \psi(r)
=
\frac{d}{dr} \left( \frac{F(r)}{r^2 \rho(r)} \right)
$$

with $\psi(r=r_\min) = \psi(r=r_\max) = 0$.

I have numeric values for all of those variables except for $\psi$ which I would like to solve for numerically.

I am looking to use scipy's [solve_bvp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html) but it requires the problem to be stated as a system of first order ODEs. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: One can always recast a second order problem $y''=f(t,y,y')$ as $x'=y,y'=f(t,x,y)$.

Comment: @Ian can you show me?

Comment: So you have 3 unknowns and 1 ODE, Right?

Comment: There is not much to show. Rewrite your equation as $\psi''=f(r,\psi,\psi')$, then you can rewrite your equation as $\psi'=y,y'=f(t,\psi,y)$.

Comment: @Narasimham My understanding is that $\rho,P,G$ and $F$ are all given.

Comment: @Narasimham 1 unknown, 1 equation, 2 boundary values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set 
$$
\varphi(r)=\frac{1}{r^2 \rho(r)} \left( \frac{d \psi(r)}{dr} \right)
-
 \frac{F(r)}{r^2 \rho(r)} 
\\~\\ \iff\\~\\
\frac{d \psi(r)}{dr} = r^2 \rho(r)\varphi(r) + F(r)
$$
so that the original equation reduces to first order
$$
\frac{dφ(r)}{dr}=-\frac{4\pi G \rho(r)}{r^2 P(r)} \psi(r)
$$
Together both equations constitute an equivalent first order system.